# Flow Linebreak in text field record update

Tags: flow, line-break

My flow runs on the Contact object. There is a screen for users to update to the Contact description. I want to combine the old description and the new one, but have a line break between them. Every method I've done so far will either not have a line break or will display the code on the record, ex. 
.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to create a line break in the Description field on your Contact record from your Flow:

1. Create a text template with a text string, followed by Enter (to go to the next line), followed by the same text string. It will look something like this where I've used the "~" character, but you can use any character you want:
   [image: Line Break Text Template]
2. Create a formula to combine the old and new descriptions with your text template as follows:
   {!OldDescrip}
   & SUBSTITUTE({!LineBreakTextTemplate}, "~", "")
   & {!NewDescrip}
3. Use your formula to update the Description field on your Contact record.

'Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you flow add a formula field "CRLF" text
CHR(13) to return the ascII text value

Note: but this does not work because of a bug in salesforce so you need to create a number field to use in the chr function chr(  {!n13}  )

Now it to set a line feed or find a line feed in an existing field

FIND( {!CRLF},  {!$Record.Street__c})